# Create New DataFrame Columns Based on Year

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame that contains NFL Quarterback Data from the 2015-2016 to the 2019-2020 Seasons. The DataFrame looks like this

```
Player             Season End Year       YPG         TD      
Tom Brady            2019               322.6        25 
Tom Brady            2018               308.1        26
Tom Brady            2017               295.7        24
Tom Brady            2016               308.7        28
Aaron Rodgers        2019               360.4        30
Aaron Rodgers        2018               358.8        33 
Aaron Rodgers        2017               357.9        35
Aaron Rodgers        2016               355.2        32
```

I want to be able to create new columns that contains the years' data I select and the last three years' data. For example if the year I select is 2019 the resulting DataFrame would be(SY stands for selected year:

```
Player          Season End Year      YPG SY             YPG SY-1      YPG SY-2     YPG SY-3      TD     
Tom Brady           2019              322.6               308.1         295.7        308.7       25
Aaron Rodgers       2019              360.4               358.8         357.9        355.2       30
```

This is how I am attempting to do it:

```
NFL_Data.loc[NFL_Data['Season End Year'] == (NFL_Data['SY']), 'YPG SY'] = NFL_Data['YPG']
NFL_Data.loc[NFL_Data['Season End Year'] == (NFL_Data['SY']-1), 'YPG SY-1'] = NFL_Data['YPG']
NFL_Data.loc[NFL_Data['Season End Year'] == (NFL_Data['SY']-2), 'YPG SY-2'] = NFL_Data['YPG']
NFL_Data.loc[NFL_Data['Season End Year'] == (NFL_Data['SY']-3), 'YPG SY-3'] = NFL_Data['YPG']
```

However, when I run the code above, it doesn't fill out the columns appropriately. Most of the rows are 0. Am I approaching the problem the right way or is there a better way to attack it?

(Edited to include TD Column)

Answer (score 3):

First step is to pivot your data frame.

```
pivoted = df.pivot_table(index='Player', columns='Season End Year', values='YPG')
```

Which yields

```
Season End Year   2016   2017   2018   2019
Player                                     
Aaron Rodgers    355.2  357.9  358.8  360.4
Tom Brady        308.7  295.7  308.1  322.6
```

Then, you may select:

```
pivoted.loc[:, range(year, year-3, -1)]
```

```
                  2019   2018   2017
Player                              
Aaron Rodgers    360.4  358.8  357.9
Tom Brady        322.6  308.1  295.7
```

Or alternatively as suggested by Quang:

```
pivoted.loc[:, year:year-3:-1]
```